# Passing Parameters from PHP to Shell

Tags: php, shell

I'd like to have 3 variables set via 3 input fields. Those variables should get passed when a button is clicked to a ShellScript.
I've got the following code...

PHP:

```
<?php
$min = "20";
$max = "50";
$norm = "70";

$var = shell_exec("action.sh $min $max $norm");
echo $var;
?>

<form>
  Min: <input type="int" name="MIN" value="<?php echo $min;?>">
  <br><br>
  Norm: <input type="int" name="NORM" value="<?php echo $norm;?>">
  <br><br>
  Max: <input type="int" name="MAX" value="<?php echo $max;?>">
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Shell:

```
typeset -i MIN
typeset -i MAX
typeset -i NORM

echo MIN, MAX, NORM
```

I've already read several QA cases on StackOverflow but not a single one actually helped. Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: What exactly is the problem with the code you are using, what is the actual result and what is the expected result?

Comment: What is the actual question? Have you read the documentation of [`shell_exec()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php) and the other [program execution functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.exec.php)? [`escapeshellcmd()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellcmd.php) and [`escapeshellarg()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php) keep you far from trouble (most of the time).

Comment: @jeroen I've got an algorhytm in the shell script. But I didn't post it because it is not relevant. The problem is that 1. The values don't get passed to the ShellScript 2. The values dont change by submitting...

Comment: I'm pretty sure the values get passed to the shell script. Perhaps you are not reading them correctly? And you need `$_GET` to get the sent-in values.

Comment: What is the issue you are having? Receiving the user input or?

Comment: @Jesse Yes, retreiving and passing the new user input to the shell script. [After an algorhytm in Shell ->] Than I'd like to get the result from the Shell Script and display it.

Comment: If you run your script from the command line, with 3 arguments, does it work ok?  Print $* in your script to see if you did receive the values.

Comment: I have made another attempt at answering your question. Please take a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to receive and pass it on to the shell, then use this:

```
<?php

if( !empty( $_POST ) ) {

$min = $_POST['MIN'];
$max = $_POST['MAX'];
$norm = $_POST['NORM'];

echo shell_exec("action.sh $min $max $norm");

}

?>

<form method="POST">
  Min: <input type="number" name="MIN" value="<?php echo $min;?>">
  <br><br>
  Norm: <input type="number" name="NORM" value="<?php echo $norm;?>">
  <br><br>
  Max: <input type="number" name="MAX" value="<?php echo $max;?>">
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: The values are saved now and it seems to work at first. Thanks for that :) But I still dont get the result from the ShellScript :/ Any ideas what the reason could?

Comment: What does echo "action.sh $min $max $norm"; output? And what is the output if you try that command in the terminal?

Comment: The Terminal delivers Percentage messages (e.g. Min=4,76%) because of the algorhytm (which ofc is correct). But the actual output on the homepage is literally nothing.

Comment: Change echo shell_exec("action.sh $min $max $norm"); to echo shell_exec("action.sh $min $max $norm 2>&1");

Comment: "sh: action.sh: command not found " gets displayed after I changed it

Comment: In what directory is the script located?

Comment: The same as the .php File

Comment: Change it to this: echo shell_exec( dirname(__FILE__) . "/action.sh $min $max $norm");

Comment: Also didnt work :-/ Could it be, that the php file doesnt get the returning value from the shell script?

Comment: Maybe use bash shell.sh ?

Comment: Didnt work neither :(  Guess im gonna quit trying for today and go on tomorrow. Thank you very much for trying to help. If you got any more ideas feel free to suggest them here. I'll look for them tomorrow.